# How to make my homepage automatically redirect to an external website?

Tags: redirect, code, frontpage

Actually, I have a website hosted by my University.
They claim that it is my personal website or whatsoever, but they do not give me full control of it!

I cannot install plugins, change the theme, or do anything I want because they edited the WordPress panel and removed all of these options.

My user is ranked as an administrator of the website. My institution user is listed as a super administrator. Besides that, I do not have FTP access or any other form of interaction besides the WordPress panel.

---

Initially, all I want was that my institution put a single HTML page that redirects to my external website, hosted elsewhere. Despite that, they give me that WordPress that I cannot control, and are not willing to change that.

My question is: how can I manage to insert a code into the home of my WordPress website that simply automatically redirects to my external website?

A photo of my panel, if it helps

[image: My panel]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it can help:

1. Go to Plugins -> Add New
2. Search for “Page Links To” plugin
3. Install and activate it
4. Create new post/page or edit an existing one
5. Scroll down to Page Links To tab
6. Choose “A Custom URL” radio button
7. Enter any URL you want
8. Choose if you want to open link in a new tab
9. Publish your post/page or update it

Comment: As I said above, I cannot install any plugin in my website. Thus, it is not an option